# How do I change the number of template arguments supported by MSVC++'s std::tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, variadic-templates, visual-c++-2012

MSVC++ doesn't yet support variadic templates, so its standard library "fakes" these for classes like `std::tuple` through use of macros. I recently tried compiling one of my projects with the VC11 beta, and got this to show for it:

```
gtest\gtest.h(9735): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\utility(72) : see declaration of 'std::tuple'
gtest\gtest.h(9743): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
gtest\gtest.h(14568): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
gtest\gtest.h(14568): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14568): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14568): error C2955: 'testing::internal::ParamGeneratorInterface' : use of class template requires template argument list
c:\users\billy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\instalog\logtests\gtest\gtest.h(10076) : see declaration of 'testing::internal::ParamGeneratorInterface'
gtest\gtest.h(14570): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
gtest\gtest.h(14581): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14581): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14586): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14586): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14593): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
c:\users\billy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\instalog\logtests\gtest\gtest.h(14593) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::CartesianProductGenerator9<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>::Iterator' being compiled
gtest\gtest.h(14593): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14593): error C2955: 'testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface' : use of class template requires template argument list
c:\users\billy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\instalog\logtests\gtest\gtest.h(10003) : see declaration of 'testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface'
gtest\gtest.h(14595): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14595): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14628): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14628): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14670): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14670): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14674): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14674): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14755): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14755): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14807): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
gtest\gtest.h(14807): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14807): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14807): error C2955: 'testing::internal::ParamGeneratorInterface' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14809): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
gtest\gtest.h(14821): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14821): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14826): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14826): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14833): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
c:\users\billy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\instalog\logtests\gtest\gtest.h(14833) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::CartesianProductGenerator10<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>::Iterator' being compiled
gtest\gtest.h(14833): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14833): error C2955: 'testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14835): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14835): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14871): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14871): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14917): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14917): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(14921): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(14921): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(15007): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(15007): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(15289): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
gtest\gtest.h(15289): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(15289): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
gtest\gtest.h(15333): error C2977: 'std::tuple' : too many template arguments
gtest\gtest.h(15333): error C3203: 'tuple' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
gtest\gtest.h(15333): error C2955: 'std::tuple' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

I've heard there's a `#define` that can be set somewhere to change this setting, but I (for the life of me) can't remember what it is. What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define `_VARIADIC_MAX` to any value between 5 and 10, inclusive.

This, and many other interesting facts about Visual C++ 11, can be found in the MSDN article, "[C++11 Features (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)."  This particular macro is discussed in the section entitled "Faux variadics."

Comment: `MSVC++` is driving me crazy! Where exactly do I need to define `_VARIADIC_MAX`? I am using `CMake` and building `GTest` as an OBJECT (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12543935/1019491)).

Comment: Nevermind, found the [solution](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=408) `add_definitions(-D_VARIADIC_MAX=10)`.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting quote from [blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) article:

> **Faux variadics:** We've developed a new scheme for simulating variadic
>   templates.  Previously in VC9 SP1 and VC10, we repeatedly included
>   subheaders with macros defined differently each time, in order to
>   stamp out overloads for 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. arguments.  (For example,
>    included the internal subheader  repeatedly, in
>   order to stamp out make_shared(args, args, args).)  In VC11, the
>   subheaders are gone.  Now we define variadic templates themselves as
>   macros (with lots of backslash-continuations), then expand them with
>   master macros.  This internal implementation change has some
>   user-visible effects.  First, the code is more maintainable, easier to
>   use (adding subheaders was a fair amount of work), and slightly less
>   hideously unreadable.  This is what allowed us to easily implement
>   variadic emplacement, and should make it easier to squash bugs in the
>   future.  Second, it's harder to step into with the debugger (sorry!). 
>   Third, pair's pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple,
>   tuple) constructor had "interesting" effects.  This requires
>   N^2 overloads (if we support up to 10-tuples, that means 121
>   overloads, since empty tuples count here too).  We initially observed
>   that this (spamming out so many pair-tuple overloads, plus all of the
>   emplacement overloads) consumed a massive amount of memory during
>   compilation, so as a workaround we reduced infinity.  In VC9 SP1 and
>   VC10, infinity was 10 (i.e. "variadic" templates supported 0 to 10
>   arguments inclusive).  In the VC11 Developer Preview, infinity is 5 by
>   default.  This got our compiler memory consumption back to what it was
>   in VC10.  **If you need more arguments (e.g. you had code compiling with
>   VC9 SP1 or VC10 that used 6-tuples), there's an escape hatch.  You can
>   define _VARIADIC_MAX project-wide between 5 and 10 inclusive (it
>   defaults to 5).**  Increasing it will make the compiler consume more
>   memory, and may require you to use the /Zm option to reserve more
>   space for PCHes.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in revision 675.
See https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/detail?r=675

Comment: +1. Gets fixed just as MSVC++ gets variadic templates :)

Comment: Hee hee :-) Well we made sure it builds cleanly on VC 12 too.

Comment: BTW if the community has come up with a standard workaround for http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/802032/std-is-copy-constructible-doesnt-work-correctly , we'd be interested. Otherwise we'll probably have to write one.