# How to make GTest build /MDd (instead of /MTd) by default, using CMake?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, googletest

I am trying to integrate **GTest** with **CMake** as seamlessly as possible. But the default build type for my test projects are `/MDd` and GTest defaults to `/MTd`. I am manually changing GTest project properties to emit debug DLL.

But every time I make changes to my `CMakeLists.txt`, GTest defaults back to `/MTd`. How do I stop this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can define `gtest_force_shared_crt` to `ON` before including gtest to achieve this. You can either do this via the command line:

```
cmake . -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON
```

or in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
```

Comment: You should add Ted Middleton's correction from below. Adding the set() line, as you suggest it, has no influence on the gtest build.

Answer (score 14):

I think a better option is @Fraser's answer - in that case, cmake + gtest 'just work'.

It's worth mentioning that in order to override the internal gtest `option` setting, you need to put the variable in the cmake cache:

```
set( gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "Always use msvcrt.dll" )
```

Comment: `FORCE` should be specified as well, see https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md.

Comment: I added FORCE and it finally worked. Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 7):

If Ted Middleton's answer doesn't work, try to use FORCE:

```
set( gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "Always use msvcrt.dll" FORCE)
```

It worked for me

Comment: This is the recommended way, according to https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md.

Answer (score 1):

We solved the problem by bypassing GTest's own build system and compiling GTest as a [CMake object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) from its unity build source file `gtest-all.cc`:

```
# compile Google Test as an object library
add_library(gtest OBJECT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest-all.cc")
set_property(TARGET gtest PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gtest-1.6.0"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gtest-1.6.0/include")
```

That way GTest will always be compiled with the same options that we use for the project.
A test executable that uses GTest can then be built in the following way:

```
add_executable(test_executable ${TESTS_SRC} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:gtest>)
add_test(NAME test COMMAND test_executable)
```

Comment: On linux, GTest depends on the `pthreads` library. How do I associate such a dependency on the `gtest` object?

Comment: Created a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560054/how-to-set-library-dependencies-on-cmake-library-objects) for this.

Comment: This way, you recompile the entire source of gtest for every separate test executable - not very efficient.  You also lose all the checks and settings that are contained in gtest's own CMakeLists.txt, one repercussion being the missing dependency on pthread on Linux.

Comment: @Fraser The gtest source is *not* recompiled for every test executable. Object libraries were precisely added as a feature to reuse a compiled object file for many targets.

Comment: @sakra - Ah yes, you're right! Sorry.  I still prefer to use GTest's own build file.  They added the `gtest_force_shared_crt` option for precisely this case.  Also, we use fairly high warning levels and treat warnings as errors, so it's convenient to have a different set of compiler options for third party libs.