# Visual Studio seemingly ignoring runtime library set in cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

There are many posts about how to set the Runtime library in Visual Studio from CMake, but in my case it seems that Visual Studio is ignoring my setting.

I would like to build google-mock with `/MD`.  This is the default setting in the project.

In a fresh build directory, built with:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\mrussell\workspace\opal2\o2win32\Libs\gtest\"1.7.0" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="/MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG" ../googlemock
```

All my cmake variables seem correct

[image: cmake-gui showing all flags have /MD]

However, when I go to build, either via the command line (I'm used to linux..) or from Visual Studio, it uses the `/MT` flag.

My build command (targeting 32 bit):

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
msbuild /m:4 /property:Configuration=%build_type% ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

Output:

```
   ClCompile:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /IC:\Users\mrussell\workspace\opal2\o2win32\Libs\gtest\g
     test\include /IC:\Users\mrussell\workspace\opal2\o2win32\Libs\gtest\gtest /Zi /nologo /W4 /WX /O2 /Ob2 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WIND
     OWS /D NDEBUG /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /D WIN32 /D _WIN32 /D STRICT /D WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN /D GTEST_HAS_PT
     HREAD=0 /D _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=1 /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MT /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t
     /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"gtest.dir\Release\\" /Fd"gtest.dir\Release\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4275 /analyze- /errorRe
     port:queue  -J "C:\Users\mrussell\workspace\opal2\o2win32\Libs\gtest\gtest\src\gtest-all.cc"
```

(note the `/MT` hiding in there.)

In Visual Studio, I open the solution, choose release type `Release`, and in any of the targets, say `gtest`, `Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Code Generation`, the `Runtime Library` is set to `/MT`, not `/MD` as set in the Cmake file.

Same thing happens if I try to build google-test (1.7.0)

Do I just not understand how to set these?  Or is there a way to force Visual Studio to use the right flag without manually opening Visual Studio and setting it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make GTest build /MDd (instead of /MTd) by default, using CMake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540970/how-to-make-gtest-build-mdd-instead-of-mtd-by-default-using-cmake)

Comment: I think one of the solutions (but not the chosen one) would actually solve my problem, but because it's not the chosen one, I'm hesitant to press the "This Solved My Problem" button.  I'll try @sakra 's solution (which matches   http://stackoverflow.com/a/12546288/1861346 ). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CMake build systems of both `google-test` and `google-mock` aren't well behaved. They do not obey the compile options and runtime option set up by the user for good reason and override those with options that they consider reasonable for testing purposes.

To prevent the replacement of `MD` with `MT` you can set the option `gtest_force_shared_crt` to `ON` in the CMake cache. The modification of other compile options (e.g., warnings) however is done unconditionally.