# Code with std::bind not compiling, error C2780: expects 6 arguments - 8 provided

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Consider the code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>

class CFileOperationWatcher
{
public:
    CFileOperationWatcher() {}

    virtual void onProgressChanged(uint64_t sizeProcessed, uint64_t totalSize, size_t numFilesProcessed, size_t totalNumFiles, uint64_t currentFileSizeProcessed, uint64_t currentFileSize) {}

    virtual ~CFileOperationWatcher() {}

    void onProgressChangedCallback(uint64_t sizeProcessed, uint64_t totalSize, size_t numFilesProcessed, size_t totalNumFiles, uint64_t currentFileSizeProcessed, uint64_t currentFileSize) {
        _callbacks.emplace_back(std::bind(&CFileOperationWatcher::onProgressChanged, this, sizeProcessed, totalSize, numFilesProcessed, totalNumFiles, currentFileSizeProcessed, currentFileSize));
    }

protected:
    std::vector<std::function<void ()> > _callbacks; 
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CFileOperationWatcher w;
    w.onProgressChangedCallback(0,0,0,0,0,0);
}
```

I'm getting an error C2780 in Visual Studio 2012. Looks like there's no `std::bind` definition that can take that many arguments. But isn't it supposed to use variadic templates and accept any number of args?

Comment: can you provide a testable code snipped (that does not depend on further code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC++ 2012 has fake variadic templates that rely on macro machinery.  By default, they only work for up to 5 parameters.  If you need more, you can use [`_VARIADIC_MAX`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) to up it as high as 10 parameters.

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589192/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-template-arguments-supported-by-msvcs-stdtupl).

VC++ added variadic templates in the 2013 version.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles fine with clang (3.3), so it must be a compiler bug with VS2012.
And yes, you're correct: `std::bind()` is a variadic template (C++11), see also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: This is definitely related to the number of argumets: I've removed two (6 total now) and it compiles and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 has no support for variadic templates. Visual Studio 2013 will on the other hand according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh409293%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Comment: VC++ 2012 doesn't support true variadic templates, but the run-time library does simulate them for a finite number of arguments using macro machinery.  You can adjust the finite number by defining _VARIADIC_MAX.